# Using two datepicker with two different date format on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datepicker

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC Web page using jQuery DatePicker.

I have the following page with two input fields using Datepicker:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="group">      
              <input type="text" 
                  name="BatchProducts[0].BatchName" 
                  id="BatchProducts[0].BatchName"
                  required />

            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="group">      
              <input type="text" class="datepicker"
                  name="BatchProducts[0].MadeDate" 
                  id="BatchProducts[0].MadeDate"
                  required />

            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="group">      
              <input type="text" class="datepicker"
                  name="BatchProducts[0].ValidateDate" 
                  id="BatchProducts[0].ValidateDate"
                  required />

            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

And the following js script:

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults(
  $.extend(
    $.datepicker.regional['es'],
    { 'dateFormat': 'yy-mm' }
  )
)

$(function () {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

My problem is that I need that `BatchProducts[0].MadeDate` with the date format `yy-mm` and `BatchProducts[0].ValidateDate` with the date format `yy-mm-dd`.

How can I do it?

This is the first time I work with this widget and I don't know how to do it. I read somewhere that I can use two different classes and use two different datepicker with each of them. But I don't know how to assign a different date format to each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){

   $(".datepicker[name='BatchProducts[0].MadeDate']").datepicker({ 'dateFormat': 'yy-mm' });
   $(".datepicker[name='BatchProducts[0].ValidateDate']").datepicker({ 'dateFormat': 'yy-mm-dd' });

});
```

Initialize them separately and pass the `format` individually.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but there will be 1 or more fields with the same name. I'm using `BatchProducts[0]` because I will have `BatchProducts[1]`, `BatchProducts[2]`, etc. input fields.

Comment: Will there be any sort of symmetry?

Comment: Maybe I can use a class for `ValidateDate` and another class for `MadeDate`. They will have the same name, I only change their index. I'm not sure if I have understood your question.

Comment: And format for MadeDate will always be yy-mm and validateDate will always be `yy-mm-dd`?

Comment: Yes, all of them (all the array elements with the same name, `ValidateDate` or `MadeDate`) will have the same format.

Comment: Then you just need to change the selectors to the appropriate class and it will work.